# Hadoop MapReduce program issue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a string line=”Hadoop is open source frame work , Hadoop is good framework for handling big data”;

I want to perform below operations inside the main method

> 1. Split the line by space and store in a new string array
> 2. Count number of occurrence of word Hadoop in the given string
> 3. Replace the ‘,’with space in the given string
> 4. Create a array list with generic string and store the spitted string inside it

Comment: Can you provide some more information in which language are you creating your map reduce program. there are some word count examples avaible on the internet  like http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/tutorial/CDH5/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount1.html

Comment: Why do you want Hadoop to this job? Using any collection object in Hadoop will make the program run poor. If its to try MapReduce, remove point-3, add it in 1 so that the string gets split even if its space or , separated. Instead of putting into ArrayList write to a context based on this condition, if(string.equalsIgoneCase("hadoop)). Get it in reducer and add.